# What are the benefits of increasing the WiFi router channel width? (Bandwidth)?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-transfer

I don't know whether increasing the channel [band] width merely disperses the same transmission power over a wider frequency range, and whether that would increase efficiency (it might if they were using CDMA, I think)

E.g.,  I can, on my TP-Link choose channel width of 20 or 40 Mhz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 802.11n can combine two 20 MHz channels to form an effective bandwidth of 40 MHz. 40 MHz enables higher data transmission rates to be
>   achieved as compared to 20 MHz. When you select 20/40 MHz mode, the
>   router decide to use 20 or 40 MHz based on the interference/contention
>   the router detected.

[Source](https://www.asus.com/support/faq/114481)

Basically set it to 20/40 auto, if you don't have an auto mode, try 40 if your not in a congested area, but if the WiFi spectrum in your area is congested it could reduce performance.

Comment: Downside is that you risk greater interference. But I used a Wifi signal detector and found a clear section (and our phones are not 2.4 Ghz, so should be nothing much besides Wifi affecting us)

Answer (score 2):

The answers to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/542191/does-moving-from-20mhz-to-40-mhz-increase-my-wireless-speed) question asked gives a good overview of the 20/40 mhz question.